# How can I insert a log entry when the user logs in the system using Serilog in a .NET Core 3 with Angular application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, serilog, action-filter

We are using Serilog in a .NET Core 3 application with Angular 9 and we log POST,PUT,DELETE methods using an action filter setup in a BaseController class using attributes like the following

```
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LoggingActionFilter))]
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, TViewEntity entity)
    {
       //do stuff...
    }
```

So far, no issue with that. When a user sends a POST,PUT,DELETE request, the system logs the respective action as expected.

However since the login consists of a razor page we cannot place an action filter there. After some web search, we've found out that we can use OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync & OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync methods implemented from IAsyncPageFilter interface.
When we try to get the user ID from the ClaimsIdentity, it returns null.

Furthermore We tried to log the user from the home page controller (right after the user has logged in) when it executes its GET method, having in mind that the referer is the login page (in order to log it only one time).

After placing the action filter attribute on the respective controller method shown below

```
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LoggingActionFilter))]
    [HttpGet("categories")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<string>>> getStatistics()
    {
        //do stuff...
    }
```

The action filter is activated and the following method is invoked in the latter...

```
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "GET" && (referer == "<value>" || referer == 
         "<another value>"))
            {
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("UserId", userId))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                }
            }
```

However the entry is not logged in the database. We are not using different properties in Serilog, than the ones used when logging the other methods mentioned above. the controller that the filter is applied to, extends the ControllerBase class.

Is there an efficient and proper way to write a log entry when the user logs in the system using Serilog?
What could possibly we have been doing wrong in the above approach ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : As per ZhiLv's mention , the code below is the configuration section for Serilog in appsettings.json file

```
  "Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "MSSqlServer",
    "Args": {
      "connectionString": "Server=theServer;Database=theDatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=user;Password=pass",
      "sinkOptionsSection": {
        "tableName": "LogTable",
        "schemaName": "dbo",
        "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        //"batchPostingLimit": 50,
        //"period": "0.00:00:05"
      },
      //"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
      "columnOptionsSection": {
        "disableTriggers": true,
        "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
        "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
        "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
        "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ],
        "additionalColumns": [
          {
            "ColumnName": "UserId",
            "DataType": "nvarchar",
            "AllowNull": false,
            "DataLength": 50
          },
          {
            "ColumnName": "ControllerAction",
            "DataType": "nvarchar",
            "AllowNull": false,
            "DataLength": 10
          },
          {
            "ColumnName": "Request",
            "DataType": "nvarchar"
          },
          {
            "ColumnName": "Response",
            "DataType": "nvarchar"
          },
          {
            "ColumnName": "StatusCode",
            "DataType": "int",
            "AllowNull": true
          }
        ],
        "id": { "nonClusteredIndex": true },
        "level": {
          "columnName": "Severity",
          "storeAsEnum": false
        },
        "timeStamp": {
          "columnName": "Timestamp"
          //"convertToUtc": true
        },
        "logEvent": {
          "excludeAdditionalProperties": true,
          "excludeStandardColumns": true
        },
        "message": { "columnName": "Message" },
        "exception": { "columnName": "Exception" }
        //"messageTemplate": { "columnName": "Template" }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Furthermore, the code used to log in the Action filter is the following:

```
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {            
        var userId = GetUserId(context.HttpContext);
        var isOnRequest = true;            
        try
        {
            //before execution                
            var requestBody = GetRequestBodyAsString(context);
            var result = await next();

            //after execution
            isOnRequest = false;

            using (LogContext.PushProperty("UserId", userId))
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("ControllerAction", context.HttpContext.Request.Method))
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("StatusCode", context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode))
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("Request", requestBody))
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("Response", JsonConvert.SerializeObject((result.Result as ObjectResult).Value)))
            {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"{context.HttpContext.Request.Method} method logged for request path: '{context.HttpContext.Request.Path}'");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var messageTemplate = isOnRequest
                ? "An error occured while sending {ControllerAction} request. User: {UserId}. Request: {Request}. Status: {StatusCode}"
                : "An error occured while receiving {ControllerAction} response. User: {UserId}. Request: {Request}. Status: {StatusCode}";
            
            _logger.LogError(ex, 
                messageTemplate, 
                context.HttpContext.Request.Method, 
                userId,
                GetRequestBodyAsString(context),
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

The above part works when logging POST PUT DELETE actions. The code below is what I'm trying to handle in order to log the user when he/she has successfully logged, in the system:

```
        public Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var result = next.Invoke();
        //get user here ?
        return result;
    }

    public Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        //trying to log the user here? it this a proper thing to do?
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("ControllerAction", context.HttpContext.Request.Method))
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("StatusCode", context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("user logged in");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Can you share us, how do you configure the Serilog to store the log message into the database and the related code in the LoggingActionFilter, in order to reproduce the problem? Besides, please check your code to make sure you are using the Serilog to log information, instead of using the Console provider?

Comment: Hello @ZhiLv, I've edited the post as per your proposal. Thank you in advance.